# How can I get this pop up box to display the value of the div clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a search box that you type in a name and a list of matching names come up using ajax. I also have a *div* that pop ups alongside the names that when clicked, another *div* pops up showing the name of the person the *div* is matched with inside of it.

Here is my code:

PHP:

```
<?php
    require 'core.inc.php';
    require 'connect.inc.php';

if (!empty($_GET['letter'])) {
    $letter = $_GET['letter'];

    $query = "SELECT `first name`, `last name` FROM `users` WHERE `first name` LIKE '".$letter."%'";
    $query_run = mysql_query($query);

    while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
        $first_name = $query_row['first name'];
        $last_name = $query_row['last name'];

        echo $first_name;
        echo " ".$last_name;    
?>
    <div id="popup" onclick="popup();"><input type="hidden" id="friend_name" name="friend_name" value="<?php print "$first_name"; print "$last_name"; ?>"></div> 
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

All of this works, it gets all the names and lists them out. Im setting the *input value* equal to the first name and last name so I can get it in javascript.

Javascript:

```
function popup() {
    var popupBox = document.createElement("div");
    popupBox.id = "popupBox";
    popupBox.innerHTML = document.getElementById('friend_name').value;
    popupboxHolder.appendChild(popupBox);
};
```

This works fine if only one name shows up, but if two names show up and I click on the second *div* the name of the first person shows up in the pop up box not the name of the second person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the element to the function using Javascript `this` to avoid all these hassles:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="popup(this);">....</div>
```

Then you can access the clicked element from your function

```
function popup(clickedelement) {
    var popupBox = document.createElement("div");
    popupBox.id = "popupBox";
    popupBox.innerHTML = clickedelement.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    popupboxHolder.appendChild(popupBox);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple divs with same id because of the while loop. try using it with a class name.

> `<div class="popup" onclick="popup();">`

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById returns the first element on the page with the id given.

the onclick function is given the context of the currently clicked element.

this == the currently clicked popup div

you code should look like this

```
function popup() {
    var popupBox = document.createElement("div");
    popupBox.id = "popupBox";
    popupBox.innerHTML = this.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    popupboxHolder.appendChild(popupBox);
};
```